# What are some practical use cases of GraphQL? When should one choose GraphQL over REST?

Tags: graphql

As I am interested in the concept of graphql I want to understand the benefits of graphql and when to use it?

Comment: This might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477655/graphql-and-round-trips-is-this-just-an-ios-app-issue/42478992#42478992

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many excellent online resources on this subject, for example https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2017/01/24/graphql-vs-rest-overview/

Main points from this article:

1. REST and GraphQL are totally different
2. GraphQL isn't a magic bullet, nor is it "better"
3. You can definitely use both at the same time
4. GraphQL is dope if used for the right thing

Comment: Thank you :) I hope this will help newcomers to understand graphQL concepts better.what it is and what it is not :) @rmuller

Comment: I'd say it is "better" than REST. I've added GraphQL API to our traditional REST API and I find myself cringing whenever I have to work with the old one. GQL FTW!

Comment: According to the official documentation, https://graphql.org/learn/best-practices/ it is not recommended to use it other endpoints at the same time

Comment: @Capaj rewriting an old API using new tech is going to feel good regardless of the paradigm used because you have learned from the mistakes of the last one. Most of what you like about GraphQL is probably completely available for REST too. https://blog.runscope.com/posts/you-might-not-need-graphql

Comment: Archived page https://web.archive.org/web/20190528142221/https://phil.tech/api/2017/01/24/graphql-vs-rest-overview/